# Error in git push heroku master " Precompiling assets failed "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to do a **git push heroku master to deploy my project** but happens the following error.

I'm following a tutorial however I have done what is asked many times and did not get success so I decided to ask for help

**It happens the following error**

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 15 column 11
   /tmp/build_1ff5086696451e8482f0d9358917ef79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `secrets'
   /tmp/build_1ff5086696451e8482f0d9358917ef79/config/initializers/uploadbox.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1ff5086696451e8482f0d9358917ef79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
```

]

```
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.1'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.3'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
#gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.

gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'slim-rails', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'start', '~> 0.1.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'uploadbox', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'bourbon', '~> 4.2.2'
gem 'neat', '~> 1.7.2'
gem 'high_voltage', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'normalize-rails', '~> 3.0.3'
gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7.2'

group :development do
  gem 'xray-rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.8'

end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'byebug'


  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

File uploadbox.rb

```
Uploadbox.retina         = true
Uploadbox.retina_quality = 30
Uploadbox.image_quality  = 70

if Rails.env.production?
  REDIS = Redis.connect(url: ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
  Resque.redis = REDIS
  Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
end

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage = :fog

  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:               'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:      Rails.application.secrets.s3_key,
    aws_secret_access_key:  Rails.application.secrets.s3_secret
  }

  config.fog_directory  = Rails.application.secrets.s3_bucket
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end

if Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  end
end
```

Comment: I suspect the problem exists on Line 16 of the following file:
config/initializers/uploadbox.rb
If you post this code then it should help in answering your question.

Comment: I added the code of uploadbox.rb file thanks for your support

Comment: Are `s3_key`, `s3_secret` and `s3_bucket` defined in `config/secrets.yml` for the production environment?  Docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html) in section 2.2.

Comment: in my **secrets.yml** file i added the code for production here is my code.

`production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  s3_key:  <%= ENV["S3_KEY"] %>
  s3_secret: <%= ENV["S3_SECRET"] %>
  s3_bucket: <%= ENV["S3_BUCKET"] %>%>
`

`code`